# Apply patch to multiple different name

Tags: diff, patch

Is it possible to apply patch to different file name but with the same structure. The case was, I have a patch of a file with specific name and then for some inevitable reason that file got changed and duplicated into multiple files but I have to apply the patch to all of that files, besides that I'm not allowed to rename that many files into the original name first.

Here's the example: (it's just an example, actual case a bit different)

> server-pc

- original file `main.cpp`
- copied and duplicated into `main_cli.cpp`, `main_tmp.cpp`, and a few `main_*.cpp`

> local-pc

- original file `main.cpp`
- got modified
- create a patch (using `diff -u`)
- get a patch file `main.patch`

So I have to apply `main.patch` from local-pc to all `main_*.cpp` files in server-pc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify that the patch is to be applied to a specific file:

```
patch -i main.patch main_cli.cpp
```

Then, it's simple enough to loop over all the files:

```sh
for f in main_*.cpp; do patch -i main.patch "$f"; done
```

Example:

```sh
$ diff -u bar foo > patch1
$ cp bar bar2
$ patch < patch1
patching file bar
$ patch -i patch1 bar2
patching file bar2
$ diff -s foo bar2
Files foo and bar2 are identical
```

Note how `patch -i patch1 bar2` patched `bar2` even though the patch file specified `bar`.

Comment: Work like charm, you really save my day, Thank you. I know this comment  was worthless and meaningless but I had to say my gratitude :)